# Missing values after joining tables in SQLite

Tags: android, join, sqlite, group-by

This is relationship between tables in SQLite database. There I am trying to join 5 tables.

[image]

```
    SELECT * FROM r_ele
WHERE r_ele.value LIKE 'でも%'
```

Query above returns this result(which is ok). **The table next to this missing words in red!**
[image: r_ele table]

But when I try join tables, some values are missing.

```
    SELECT e.id AS entry_id,
re.value AS re_value,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ke.value) AS ke_value,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.value) AS g_value
FROM (entry e
INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk
INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk
INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk
INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk)
WHERE g.lang IS NULL AND re_value LIKE 'でも%'
GROUP BY re.value
ORDER BY re_value;
```

Result:
[image: joing 5 tables:entry, r_ele, k_ele, sense, gloss]

What I am doing wrong? What should I do in order to avoid missing some values from table 'r_ele'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN to include all records from the left table, even if there are no matching records in the right table.

Comment: Won't be problem if I change all INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs like this:FROM (entry e
LEFT JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk
LEFT JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk
LEFT JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk
LEFT JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk)